# how do i find shapegeometry/object3d in three.js?

Tags: three.js, editor

Imagine I've got Scene full of some [Mesh,AmbientLight,Object3D] and I'd like to intersect (while mouse moves over them).

problem:
 THREE.js only intersects everything but Object3D

extraNotes:
 I already now recursive param and more than 1 object can be intersected. (z)

Comment: three.js intersects Object3D also.

Comment: So then what is the question?